# How to hide an empty ZStack in a List?

Tags: swiftui

I am loading an ad when the corresponding view appears in a `List`.

[image: Banner ad]

```
import SwiftUI

enum LoadingState: Int {
    case loading
    case loaded
    case error
    case none
}

struct TestAd: View {
    
    @State var state: LoadingState = .none
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            switch state {
            case .loading:
                ProgressView()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            case .loaded:
                Color.yellow
            default:
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 60)
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .onAppear {
            refreshAd()
        }
    }
    
    func refreshAd(){
        Task {
            state = .loading
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(10e9))
            state = .loaded
        }
    }
}

struct TestAd_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                TestAd()
                
                Section("Items") {
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 2")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Items")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that an empty `ZStack` is still displayed inside a `List`. If I use an `EmptyView`, then I can't use `onAppear` to refresh the ad.

[image: Empty ZStack]

```
NavigationStack {
            List {
                ZStack {
                    
                }
                .onAppear {
                    print("APPEAR ZSTACK")
                }
                
                EmptyView()
                    .onAppear {
                        print("APPEAR EMPTY_VIEW")
                    }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Items")
        }
```

```
APPEAR ZSTACK
```